# How to show a link to attachments in ssrs that replaces the output "True" and "False"? from a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, attachment

I am currently getting true/false outputs where there are attachments, but I was wondering how I can turn those true or false outputs into a link where the user will be able to click it and sends them to that document. I am using a sharepoint database to get my values.
Please advise on how I can accomplish this.

Thank you

Lucky

Answer (score 0):

in the cell or text box properties, you can use the "Action" feature. Choose goto URL and click the Formula button.

For the formula, test of the filed is true or false, to use or not use the url you want to go to.

```
=IIF(Fields!ShowURL.Value="True", "http://www.google.com", "")
```

This assumes the 'True' 'False' are strings as apposed to unquoted Booleans.
The IIF statement will use the URL if the condition is met for the 'showURL field, and have no value if it is not.